# Starting Android Emulator On Jenkins Gives WindowServer Error

Tags: testing, jenkins, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins, android-emulator-plugin

How can I get the android emulator running on jenkins for my testing (MacOSX Server)?
I have tried the plugin, gives same error (yes I unchecked 'show window'), so I executed a shell script of my own on jenkins during build and I get the same error. Why does it even care about the WindowServer when i have -no-window, doesn't make sense. And if it's a permission problem why am I not getting the error WindowServer permission error?
My console output:

```
./android create avd -n testEmu -t 14 -c 2000M
./emulator -avd testEmu -no-skin -no-audio -no-window

_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
2014-07-03 15:45:16.295 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.296 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.296 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.296 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.297 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.297 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.297 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.297 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.298 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.298 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.298 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.298 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.298 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.298 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.299 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
2014-07-03 15:45:16.299 emulator64-arm[6408:d07] invalid CoreGraphics connection
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
```

Comment: Probably not relevant, but FYI according to the [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) page, you've misspelled the `-noaudio` and `-noskin` args (no `-` after `no`...)